# How to get string of UTF-8 or ASCII instead of UTF-16 by default?

Tags: java, android, char

I am getting string from EditText and can't transform it to byte array properly because it (as I understood) coded in UTF-16. Can I set that all the characters written in the string are in ASCII or UTF-8 by default? Or can I transform UTF-16 to UTF-8 or ASCII somehow?

The only way I have found to solve my problem is to create self-made code table, is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, a `String` is a sequence of Unicode characters (or code points, see footnote 1). You can normally ignore how Java stores that in its memory. Important is only the fact that a Java `String` can hold any sequence of Unicode charaters.

When talking about things like ASCII, UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 or similar, they are encodings, rules how to represent characters as bytes. And Java has built-in support for all relevant encodings, e.g. to get an ASCII-encoded byte sequence you can use

```
byte[] asciiBytes = string.getBytes("US-ASCII");
```

Now you can say that `asciiBytes` holds an ASCII encoding of the given `string`.

One final recommendation: try to avoid encodings in the core of your code, use it only when reading or writing files with text content. And classes like `InputStreamReader` allow you to specify the file encoding.

---

(1) There still is a fine distiction between characters and code points, which we will ignore for the purpose of this answer.

Comment: Tried to do this, but the problem is that I get wrong bytes. For example, i have `String a = "ababccd"` , and after using this method I get 7 bytes (10000110 01000110 10000110 01000110 11000110 11000110 00100110) but decimal values of these bytes don't match with their ASCII codes. For example, 01000110 = 70 in decimal system, but it is not 'c' in ASCII table, but 'F'.

Comment: So, when I transform it back to char it shows not 'c' but 'F'

Comment: You're somehow reading the bits in your bytes from the wrong end. Instead of 10000110, read it as 01100001, and you get the ASCII code of an "a", as expected. As a reference, show the byte values with `Integer.toBinaryString(asciiBytes[i])`. Most probably, the byte values are perfectly ok, you're only viewing them by a misbehaving string conversion.

Comment: Oh yes, that was totally my error, was reading bits in wrong way earlier in my program. Thank you for pointing it!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can easy do it. Example:

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(myString)
```